# VSCode Debug console customization

Tags: visual-studio-code, bunyan

I've a project that i'm using Bunyan logger as logger agent. But the Bunyan logs with the json format the debug texts, and this make difficult to read the output:

[image: Debug console with Bunyan format]

But Bunyan provides a CLI tool to humanize the log that converts the JSON to a readable text:

[image]

What I want's is create an extension to enable Bunyan console format to the Debug output text, automatic transforming the json output to debug text. But in VSCode extension development API I couldn't find any reference to manipulate debug console.
I if can manipulate de Debug console message, I could return te messages well formatted as Bunyan format.
So my question is if have some documentation to manipulate debug console messages or how i can work with debug console messages in my vscode extension.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I have found the answer by myself. I can do this simply changing my Debugger configurations, setting args and console type as the follow:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "node",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Launch Program",
            "program": "${workspaceRoot}/app.js",
            "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
            "args": [
                "|",
                "bunyan"
            ],
            "console": "integratedTerminal"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: you could clean up this answer to be minimal

Comment: unfortunately the provided configuration doesn't work on windows (I still see the original json in the integrated terminal)